# Python - If array is in range of other array

Tags: python, arrays, key, range, contains

Meaning "if each item is within range of other item with the same index".

```
price = [1, 2]  
budget = [5, 7]
```

This works:

```
if price[0] in range(budget[0]) and price[1] in range(budget[1]):
    affordable = True
```

I figure there's some way to just reference the whole array though. Like so: `if price in budget:`

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "within range"? What is a range of a single item? What determines whether the price is "in budget" here?

Comment: You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all); e.g. `if all(price[i] in range(budget[i]) for i in range(...))` or `all(p in range(b) for p,b in zip(price, budget))` if that's what you really want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
if all(x in range(y) for x,y in zip(price,budget)):
    affordable = True
```

This will create tuples of `price[i],budget[i]` and then for each of these tuples we check that `price[i]` is in `range(budget[i])`. Nevertheless, you can optimize this further to:

```
if all(0 <= x < y for x,y in zip(price,budget)):
    affordable = True
```

Note that this makes the assumption that `price`s are **all** integers. If you however use `x in range(y)` it will fail if `x` is not an integer. So `0.7 in range(10)` would fail whereas our second approach will succeed (but it depends of course on what you want).

Comment: Using range would also fail if budget isn't an integer

Comment: `0<=x<=y` (or similar) instead of `x in range(y)` will deal with floats and not compile (and iterate; PY2) a `list`

Comment: That'd do it, thanks :) I just remembered what I actually need in my case was to check for either instead of both, here's how to do it in that case:             `if any(x not in range(y) for x, y in zip(price, budget)):`

Comment: @schwobaseggl: what do you mean with "*not compile*"?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In Python2, `range` builds (compiles) a list of integers first, and then must iterate it again for the contains check, which seems like a lot work to check if some numerical values lies between two other numerical values. compile = build, put together, not in the computational sense of 'translate' ;)

Comment: @schwobaseggl: ah yeah indeed. This comparison works in *O(1)* whereas `range(..)` in Python-2.x works indeed in *O(n)*.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that both prices and budgets must be non-negative, using `in range` seems to be over-complicating things. Instead, you could just use the `<` operator.

Regardless of whether you use `<` or `in range`, it seems like the easiest approach would be to `zip` both lists and apply the condition on the pairs:

```
if (all([x[0] >= x[1] for x in zip(budget, price)])):
    affordable = True
```